# Tallying up similar SQL rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that is described with two columns: an index, and a date.

How would I run a query so that: for each date, it tallies how many entries are for that date, and does it for every date that appears?

I know I can COUNT for a specific date, but I'm lost as to how to do this for each date.

(I'm using SQLite, but a description for any SQL language would be very helpful). Thanks!

Comment: Aggregate function plus GROUP BY.

Comment: I was missing GROUP BY; completely forgot =\ Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

```
select `date`, count(*) 
from your_table
group by `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select index, date, COUNT(*) from tbl
group by index, date
```

check this.... let me know if it works.....

Answer (score -1):

If a field is not in the "group by" list then you cannot include it unless you are performing some aggregate function on it (count, sum, etc.).

```
select "date_field", count(*)  from "table" group by "date_field";
```

Also, SQLite does not have to use backticks (`) like MySQL, you can use double quotes.

Comment: SQLite uses backticks.

Comment: Ah, I see you are correct. It can use the SQL standard double quotes, however.

Comment: No, then SQLite interpretes this as just a static string instead of a column name.

Comment: Wasn't there some point at which backticks did not work in SQLite?

Comment: @juergen-d I don't think that is true, give it a try.

Comment: That is, it interprets it as a string if the column name does not exist.

Comment: You are wrong. Your statement does not even compile. Try it yourself here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Worked for me. You have to use sqlite, not MySQL. (SQL.js).

Comment: All right. I take it back. It did work when the column exists. Wow. Didn't know that :)

Comment: :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/04eca/66/0 I have to admit I think it is weird. I prefer MySQL backticks myself.